# Chaining grafana variables

Tags: prometheus, chaining, grafana-variable

How do you chain grafana variables to filter template panels
Grafanav6.2.5
Datasource: prometheus
Data: Kubernetes metrics

I want to be able to select the first variable e.g. Cluster, then select the second variable which shows only say nodes in that cluster. Or select a Namespace variable and only pods in that namespace

I'm using Node Exporter and Kube-State-Metrics with some standard dashboards from Git etc which work fine but don't want to apply the filter at the panel level.

`label_values(node)`
Works fine showing my available nodes.

`label_values($cluster, node)`
Parse error

`label_values({cluster="$cluster"}, node)`
Doesn't work and breaks the variable instead of showing nodes in that cluster.

I either get parsing errors or the variable declaration saves without complaining but doesn't function as expected or at all. Has anyone ever had this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably you've got wrong order of variables in list. When At top you've got cluster, and second is node and they're refreshing on time range change it should work. You can also try

```
label_values(kube_node_info{cluster="$cluster"}, node)
```

Which will go through less metrics each time

Comment: Hero, that works perfectly. I don't think grafana likes it when using All values too but removed that in favor of selecting a cluster. Thanks!